# Табы на чистом CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Для реализации табов использую :target, но при загрузке страницы нужно чтобы первый блок был видим. Блоки будут выводится динамически. Реально это сделать без JS?

```css
.target:not(:target){
   display: none;
}
      
.target:target{           
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><a href="#id1">Блок 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#id2">Блок 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#id3">Блок 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#id4">Блок 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="target" id="id1">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempus, felis at varius eleifend, neque orci porta magna, consequat aliquam ligula velit quis erat. Aenean porttitor pellentesque risus, eu tincidunt ipsum blandit in. </p>
</div>

<div class="target" id="id2">
   <p>Sed lobortis placerat elit tincidunt tempor. Nam dignissim euismod quam nec tempor. Sed tortor lorem, ultricies a auctor nec, auctor ut neque. Aenean varius, urna eget adipiscing feugiat, nunc ligula molestie massa, id accumsan turpis metus ac ante. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
</div>
  
<div class="target" id="id3">
   <p>Pellentesque quis tortor vitae elit cursus vulputate et vel dui. Nunc commodo pretium arcu in ultricies. Nunc vel velit enim, et tincidunt leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
</div>
  
<div class="target" id="id4">
   <p>Quisque eget tempor sapien. Cras convallis tempor orci pulvinar scelerisque. Nullam et erat eu nibh sollicitudin congue sit amet id diam. Sed in lectus ut augue euismod porta. Quisque non lacus odio. Nunc ornare adipiscing egestas. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `.target:first-child { display: block }`, хотя не уверен, что при динамическом добавлении блоков будет работать адекватно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться классом, для указания элемента открытого по умолчанию, и [sibling селектором](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), позволяющем выбирать соседний элемент на уровне.

В данном подходе есть ограничение: элемент открытый по умолчанию должен быть *последним* в разметке.

Пример, [на основе ответа на английский вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354472/2881286):

```css
.target:not(:target),
:target ~ .target.default-target {
  display: none;
}
.target:target,
.target.default-target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#id1">Блок 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#id2">Блок 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#id3">Блок 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#id4">Блок 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="target" id="id2">
  <p>Sed lobortis placerat elit tincidunt tempor. Nam dignissim euismod quam nec tempor. Sed tortor lorem, ultricies a auctor nec, auctor ut neque. Aenean varius, urna eget adipiscing feugiat, nunc ligula molestie massa, id accumsan turpis metus ac ante.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
</div>

<div class="target" id="id3">
  <p>Pellentesque quis tortor vitae elit cursus vulputate et vel dui. Nunc commodo pretium arcu in ultricies. Nunc vel velit enim, et tincidunt leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
</div>

<div class="target" id="id4">
  <p>Quisque eget tempor sapien. Cras convallis tempor orci pulvinar scelerisque. Nullam et erat eu nibh sollicitudin congue sit amet id diam. Sed in lectus ut augue euismod porta. Quisque non lacus odio. Nunc ornare adipiscing egestas.</p>
</div>

<div class="target default-target" id="id1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempus, felis at varius eleifend, neque orci porta magna, consequat aliquam ligula velit quis erat. Aenean porttitor pellentesque risus, eu tincidunt ipsum blandit in.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачастую используют input для подобной реализации. Вот готовый пример:

```css
input, .content {
    display: none;
}

#one:checked ~ .one,
#two:checked ~ .two,
#three:checked ~ .three {display: block;}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

label:hover, input:checked + label {background: #eee;}

h3, p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="nav" id="one" checked="checked"/>
<label for="one">What</label>

<input type="radio" name="nav" id="two"/>
<label for="two">Where</label>

<input type="radio" name="nav" id="three"/>
<label for="three">Why</label>

<article class="content one">
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</article>

<article class="content two">
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
    <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
</article>

<article class="content three">
    <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
</article>
```

Comment: а вас не смущает, что исходный пример очень далек от аккордеона на css и есть меню, на которое нужно нажимать, чтобы блоки появились?

Comment: Откройте код на весь экран

Comment: вы полностью поменяли код, поэтому опровергать мой ответ уже без толку, и надо бы об этом указывать, к тому же ваш новый ответ опять не подходит и совершенно не учитывает динамичность добавления блоков, представьте что у вас будет 100 таких блоков, как вы будет нумеровать меню и прописывать стили в css, вручную?

Comment: Очень жаль, что вы не посмотрели первый пример в полном экране. Он был со всеми стилями и медиа-запросом, поэтому в узком блоке выглядел в виде вертикальных табов. Новый пример более прост в разметке, поэтому я использовал именно его, чтоб не было подобных вопросов. По поводу динамичности, то тут у каждого свои потребности и с большим количеством блоков стоит использовать JS.

Comment: я посмотрел ваш первый пример, в истории, да там есть переключение в большом окне :) но в любом случае с ним то же самое, что и со вторым примером, он не рассчитан на динамичность. Посмотрите вариант @Grundy, там нет JS и там весь css работает через классы

Comment: Может еще и выделение активного пункта списка можно реализовать? Повторюсь, любой способ будет полезно рассмотреть, все зависит от ситуации.